# Can/Should C++ #pragma Preprocessors Reside In Functions

Tags: c++, winapi, linker, pragma, common-controls

In short, I am wanting to make a function that embeds the visual styles manifest and links to `ComCtl32.lib`, version 6 if available. Here is basically what I am hoping to do:

```
void InitVivify() {
    // Embed visual style XML manifest
    #pragma comment(linker,                           \
        "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32'"          \
        "   name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'" \
        "   version='6.0.0.0'"                        \
        "   processorArchitecture='*'"                \
        "   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df'"        \
        "   language='*'\""                           \
    )

    // Link common controls library
    #pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

    // Initialize controls used
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrlEx;
    InitCtrlEx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    InitCtrlEx.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_USEREX_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrlEx);
}
```

I realize this probably isn't good practice, but is it valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pragma directives are pre-processor directives.
They cause the implementation to behave in a implementation defined way.
So it is valid but not encouraged.

C++11 Standard:

**16.6 Pragma directive [cpp.pragma]**

> 1 A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # pragma pp-tokensopt new-line
> ```
>
> causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner. Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.

Comment: Ah I see, **pre** processor should be my hint. Every pre-processor will be evaluated reguardless of where I put it, because it is BEFORE the compilation begins. So even though putting it in a function can be done, it won't give me the desired behavior I am after. I intended to make this function a part of a static library, so others can link to it and call the function, and thus `ComCtl32.lib` would then be linked in THEIR program. But from what you are telling me I can see that most likely isn't how it will work.